# FileInputStream error No such file or directory

Tags: enoent

The issue is that when I run my program in Android Studio the FileInputStream can't find the c:\poi-test.xls file.

The simple test java program that I'm running in Android Studio is:

```
try {

    File file = new File("C:\\poi-test.xls");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Android Studio I step through and the file object is created but when I step through the FileInputStream I get the following error:

C:\poi-test.xls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I've spent hours trying to resolve the issue via SO and google and haven't found a solution.

The complete error listing is:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.jake.testforreadxls-1/lib/x86_64
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
**W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\poi-test.xls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err:     at com.jake.testforreadxls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:   ... 14 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8734', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Just to verify the obvious...the file is in the correct directory and the path has been verified.

Answer (score 0):

App running inside emulator/android device cannot access the file system of your PC. Android OS has no idea where `C:\\poi-test.xls` is. File must be stored on your sd card of internal storage of your device for your solution to work.